# $p^2=2q^2$ $ p,q \in \mathbb {N} $ ??

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Do we have any possibility that we get ,

$ p^2 = 2q^2 $, $ \forall p,q \in {N} $

I just reading the properties of Square Numbers on [ [Properties of Square numbers](https://www.ask-math.com/properties-of-square-numbers.html#:%7E:text=In%20this%20section%20we%20will,%2C%203%2C%207%20or%208.&text=Property%202%3A%20The%20number%20of,perfect%20square%20is%20always%20even.) ]

I found that property no.7:  There are $n$ natural numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $p^2 = 2q^2$.
I tried but did not get any pair of numbers.

I tried some  examples:

1. If we have $12^2=144=2(72)$, and $72$ is not perfect square
2. $10^2=100=2(50)$, and $50$ is not perfect square
3. $ 22^2=484=2(242)$, and $242$ is not a perfect square
4. $ 16^2=256=2(128)$, $128$ is not perfect square.

**Do we have any possibility with $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p^2=2q^2$ holds?**

Comment: We can't have $p^2=2q^2$ with $p,q\in\mathbb N$, because otherwise $\pm\sqrt2=p/q$, which contradicts the fact that $\sqrt2$ is irrational

Comment: @lulu $p^2=2q^2 \to (1)$ , Sir its mean this equation a name as equation no.1 so it doesn't need to write $p^2=2q^2 $ again and again. If u think thats something not understandable . i will edit the question

Comment: "There are $n$ natural numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $p^2=2q^2$" .   I checked the website that you referenced, which does actually give the above assertion.  This is a **typo** on the website.  The assertion should read: "There are **no** natural numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $p^2=2q^2$" .

Comment: @user2661923 Okay Sir I got it..

Answer (score 2):

One way to see that this is not possible is, as was mentioned in the comments, it contradicts the irrationality of $\sqrt 2$. In fact, this is usually used to prove that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

To see that this is impossible, suppose by way of contradiction that such a $p$ and $q$ exist. We can assume that $p$ and $q$ are coprime. Then, $p^2 = 2q^2$ implies that $p^2$ is even, and thus $p$ is also even. But, then $4$ divides $p^2$ and thus also divides $2q^2$. This implies that $q^2$ is even and so $q$ is even. This contradicts the assumption that $p$ and $q$ are coprime.

Comment: Got it Sir. I was just confused due to that website property

Answer (score 2):

$q^2$ is a square for definition, so the exponent of $2$ present in the prime factorization of $q^2$, as well as the exponent of every other prime, must be even. Doubling $q^2$ changes that exponent from even to odd. But if the prime factorization of $2q^2$ has $2$ raised to an odd exponent, it can't be a square, since no square has an odd exponent in its prime factorization.